# How to force evaluation inside the body of a pure function?

Tags: evaluation, pure-function

For example, I'm writing a function to scale my list of numbers into a specific range. It goes like

```
ScaleTo[data_, range_] := (# - Min[data]) (Last[range] - First[range]) / (Max[data] - Min[data]) & /@ data
```

But as I found out, the value of `Last[range] - First[range]`, `Max[data] - Min[data]` will be evaluated for each element being scaled although the values are always the same. Using a temporary variable to store the function would solve the problem

```
ScaleTo[data_, range_] := Module[{ScaleFunc},
    ScaleFunc[x_] = (x - Min[data]) (Last[range] - First[range])/(Max[data] - Min[data]);
    ScaleFunc /@ data]
```

Is there a better way? Besides, if I substitute the second line with

```
ScaleFunc = (# - Min[data]) (Last[range] - First[range]) / (Max[data] - Min[data]) &;
```

It wouldn't be evaluated until called. Why is that? Thanks!

Comment: Try to use `Evaluate` somewhere you want it to be evaluated so that temporary variable is unnecessary

Comment: This is a great use case for `With`.

Comment: It's trivial in this case (not to mention there is a built-in function `Rescale`): `ScaleTo[data_, 
  range_] := (data - 
    Min[data]) (Last[range] - First[range])/(Max[data] - Min[data])`. So you don't need a pure function at all.

Comment: As of 10.1 one could also use `MinMax` and save one evaluation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with the last line, when you define

```
ScaleFunc = (# - 
      Min[data]) (Last[range] - First[range])/(Max[data] - Min[data]) &;
```

the `HoldAll` attribute of the `&` (see [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)) prevents `data` and `range` to receive any values. As soon as you then apply `ScaleFunc` to an argument, say `ScaleFunc[Range[10]]`, the functions `Min` etc. in the function body do evaluate their arguments because they themselves as usual.

This `HoldAll` effect doesn't occur when you use the definition

```
Clear[ScaleFunc,x];
ScaleFunc[x_] = (x - Min[data]) (Last[range] - First[range])/(Max[data] - Min[data]);
```

as you do in the `Module`. There, it would actually have been safer to use `SetDelayed` instead of `Set` because `x` is a global variable as written (I added the `Clear` just because I pulled things apart from your `Module` for the sake of discussion).

Since you want to use a pure function somehow, we should try to modify the ingredients of your `Module` accordingly. Here are two suggestions that get by without `Module` but use functions in rather different ways:

```
ScaleTo[range_] := 
 With[{del = Last[range] - First[range]}, (# - Min[#]) del/(Max[#] - Min[#]) &]

ScaleTo[range_] := Function[d, (d - Min[d]) #/(Max[d] - Min[d])] &[
  Last[range] - First[range]]
```

Both approaches separate the `range` from the second argument because `range` contains parameters that we don't want to be fed into a re-evaluation every time the second argument (`data`) is supplied.

The first version uses `With` as suggested by @march. It substitutes the calculated value of `del` when you call `ScaleFunc` with a `range` argument. The result is a function that can be applied to `data`.

The same result is also achieved in the second version, but there I use `Function` to define it. In addition, the `range` information is injected into the definition of that function by another (pure) function (that's what `With` did in the previous version).

The explanation why we need `With` or a sequence of two functions is again the `HoldAll` attribute of `Function`. `With` gets around this attribute because it makes literal substitutions inside its scope, and the `#` inside `Function` together with `&` allow evaluation of `Last[range]-First[range]` before defining the `Function`, because that intermediate step is calculated outside the function body.